# Is it possible to cross-play Minecraft Pocket Edition with PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can you cross-play with people playing in Minecraft Pocket Edition, with Minecraft PC edition?

I don't have the digital money, or the permission to pay for Minecraft PE, and all of my friends are on the Pocket Edition, and I want to play with them.

Comment: Some of the answers in the linked duplicate are outdated, but I believe the one with the bounty awarded to it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is currently not possible to play on the same server with Minecraft Java Edition and Minecraft Pocket/Windows 10 Edition and it is also not planned to add that ability.

But, if your PC has Windows 10, you can get the Windows 10 Edition for free if you go to this page: http://account.mojang.com/me